# Combining 2 form actions into one form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mailchimp

I currently have two forms doing two separate actions.

One form subscribes a user to a mailchimp list. The other allows a user to submit their cv.

However I have two submit buttons, one for each action. I want to condense this down to just one submit.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSVY8/

```
.
```

The end result should be that on submission the CV should be sent to me, and then the form for mailchimp should be submitted.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Cheers, Matt

Comment: why not condense into one form, send data to your server and update Mailchimp API from your server? Seems more user friendly

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different actions, so you need to different forms! Without the  tag, the input button is useless anyway!
Validate the form in both client-side and server-side

So just wrap each submit button in a different form with a different action/validation and you're done!